# Symfony 4 - How to organize my form collection?

Tags: php, symfony, collections

In my Symfony 4 project, I have a Validator entity that contains the 'order' and 'user' fields that refer to a user of my User entity.

The goal is to allow the site administrator to establish a list of users who can validate certain requests from other users, but with a specific order.

For example, the admin would establish the following list:

```
1. Philippe Dupont

2. Julia Robert

3. Joseph Dupuis
```

He would have the possibility on the page to dynamically add elements, or to change the order of the validators as he wishes by passing Joseph Dupuis in 1st position for example.

So, it would look a little like what we see on this page using a jQuery plugin
https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/

(But I'm under Symfony 4 )

[Image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGjMj.png)

The goal being the submission of the form to be able to obtain in this case 3 validator objects that will contain the correct order (1,2,3) with the right User elements according to what has been entered. And everything will be spent on the BDD.

Except that in addition to being able to do that, it would be necessary that on each fields text, there is an automatic filtering on the complete name of the user with each modification of the field.

So I would like to have your help to know how I should go about doing all this. Is this plugin the right solution? Is it easy to set up on Symfony 4? Ability to add a filter effect?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take what you want to do a step at a time. You are asking for 2 different things here, and there isn't a pre-built javascript library that will do both.

Start with creating your "Validator" input form form. It sounds like [select2.js](https://select2.org) will help you with your auto-complete request.  Your User field would be a EntityType or ChoiceType.

Then move on to creating a collection of these forms following the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html). The collection script you linked should work with Symfony 4 with tweaking, as form collections really didn't change much between 3.x and 4.x.